# MVC - model to a json object

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I had a mvc object as my model.

I need to stringfiy my model as a json object type - and then use it in js as i please.

i currently doing something like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        var jsonData2 = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
        showBeginDate(jsonData2);
    });
</script>
```

But when i try to acess a json property for exemple as jsonData2.BeginDate I keep getting undefined. 
jsonData2 is a json object - why can i "read" from it?

Regards

Comment: Did you try JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))');

Comment: Its just `var jsonData2 = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` (no quotes - by adding the quotes your making it a string and you would then need to parse it back to JSON)

Answer (score 1):

@riteshmeher 's suggestion is correct

```
var text = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';           
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
```

I don't know your model so I created a simple model with 2 attributes: Id and Name. In case that the model is a list, you can read it:

```
// Access to object in position 1 
var result = obj[0].Id + " - " + obj[0].Name;
```

In other case, access right to the property.

```
var result = obj.Id + " - " + obj.Name;
```

For more info, check this post:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_properties.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/json/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_parse

**UPDATE**

like @Stephen Muecke said, better this:

```
var obj = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));           
var result = obj[0].Id + " - " + obj[0].Name;
```

thank @Craig for the corrections